# Get users to add hangouts chat bot by clicking link

Tags: google-hangouts

I want hangouts chat users in my company to add a hangouts chat bot by clicking on a link.

I have created a bot in my companies hangouts chat environment, and it can only communicate once a user has added it. The bot is designed to proactively chase users, so the bot always initiates the chat. It is not able to do this if the user hasn't added the bot.

I can't find a way to automatically add the bot to all users in the company (if this is actually possible and anyone knows how to do it please let me know), so I need to find a way to reduce the barrier for people to add the bot. I want to send out automated emails with a link; when clicked it will add the bot to the users hangouts chat.

Is this possible, and if so what is the format of the link?